# Windows analog to Unix' 'ipcs -m' command

Tags: windows

Does Windows have the notion of system-wide shared memory segments and is there a command for listing them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest program I can think of for inspecting this would be [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx). You will be able to look for shared memory segments (possibly called "sections", I'm not at a Windows machine right now so I can't check) in the list of open handles for processes.

Windows does not support shared memory sections that exist without a process that is holding a  handle to them. So no, there is no direct equivalent to `ipcs -m`.